# Updating TextView in onCreate()

Tags: android

I want to update `TextView`  in `onCreate()`, so that text should be set when `Activity` Interface appears, what I've tried is:

Java Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sem_selection);

    TextView T =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    T.setText("required text"); 

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

but i get error when activity starts , as soon as i comment this line :

```
T.setText("required text");
```

App runs fine without error. How should I do this? Is there any other method?

Comment: Your `textView1` is probably in `PlaceholderFragment`. Move it to `onCreateView`

Comment: What error? Post your LogCat/Stacktrace

Comment: yeah , that had to be inside onCreatView() , solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `TextView T` from `fragment` you will get null because in your activity you are using `activity_sem_selection` and getting TextView `T` from  `activity_sem_selection` layout.

So use `T` in `onCreateView` method of fragment.

For example

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__sem_selection, container,
                false);

        TextView T =(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        T.setText("required text"); 

        return rootView;
    }
```

Note : change  `fragment__sem_selection` with your fragment layout.

Comment: And also, it is better practice to use lowercase letters for variables - `TextView t` and not `T`

Comment: Thanks alot #Giru bhai  :) it worked perfectly , now i just couldn't get the mistake i was making previously , it was a null pointer exception , i am a beginner , kindly elaborate , thanks in advance .

Comment: accepted :)p.s i just asked for a little explanation about my mistake , sir '

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `textView1` is present in `activity_sem_selection` layout.Otherwise you will get `NPE`.Try to place a `TextView` with id *textView1* in `activity_sem_selection` layout. Otherwise you can remove those assignment and referencing for that `TextView` T and place those inside `fragment's` onCreateView(...).