# setText android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

[screenshot of how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94GeQ.png)So i'm trying to create a quiz application on android but while working on it, i noticed that the setText i used to set first question and answers is not working, it would be great if you help me find out what's not working here.
Notice that the problems occurs only when trying to set text programmatically

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;       
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Play extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button a1,a2,a3,a4;
private TextView question;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    a1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.a1);
    a2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.a2);
    a3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.a3);
    a4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.a4);
    question = findViewById(R.id.question);
    question.setText("Pick");
    a1.setText("A");
    a2.setText("B");
    a3.setText("C");
    a4.setText("D");
}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".Play">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/a2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/a3"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a2"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/a4"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/answer3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/a1"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="364dp"
    android:layout_height="264dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/a1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
/>
```

Comment: what error showing?

Comment: i added in post a screenshot of what i get when i run it, the buttons and text view are blank

Comment: i think there is no error. just you have to rearrange your layout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android widget: How to change the text of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851507/android-widget-how-to-change-the-text-of-a-button)

Comment: I saw this post too, i made the code as simple as possible to track the problem but still get nothing, buttons' text is still blank. Thanks anyway

Comment: Does it work if you setText in xml file?

Comment: yes it works fine

Comment: Any error logs?
Btw, you can reference this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925766/updating-textview-in-oncreate

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code, its showing result as expected. Try to change text color of your button text. or by setting background color of your views to check which view is appearing first. Sometimes code is working but due to some view over other, it does not reflect output

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
import android.widget.View;
```

at the top of your java file.

[Android widget: How to change the text of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851507/android-widget-how-to-change-the-text-of-a-button)

Comment: Hi, i added it but still no change. I checked that post too and my code looks ok compared to what's there, weird.

Comment: It have no sense but if you declare Button inside onCreate inline? Button a1 = etc..

Comment: i did that too, but it makes no change

Comment: Check if findViewById method works fine (implement onClick). Are there some errors in Logcat?

Comment: yeah, i think there's a problem with my findViewById implemented an onClick an app close whenever i click

Comment: Can you share Logcat screen?